# Animal Crossing New Leaf male character personalities

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Are there any male characters on Animal Crossing New Leaf with personalities other than “lazy” or “jock”?
Pretty sexist really, Nintendo

Comment: Julian is smug, so it is neither lazy nor jock. I'm pretty sure that there are more like this.

Comment: Nintendo probably don't expect hounds to target their games with remarks like this... Because it's a game. The market is children! They don't care :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [New Leaf wiki](http://new-leaf.wikia.com/wiki/Personalities), the in-game male personalities are the limited to:

- Jock
- Cranky
- Lazy
- Smug

Comment: Xander just an FYI that I'm pretty sure GunsBlazing was actually laughing at the personality types, and not anything wrong with your answer.